# How to figure out which code is required in linux kernel porting and upgrading

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to porting 2.6 kernel to 3.4 kernel.
There are many patches in the 2.6 kernel for specific hardware.
What's the effective method to figure out which directories I require to modify and patch on new 3.4 kernel?

Is there tool or script to reduce the code which I should deep into?